# Can't access Apollo classes in Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, apollo-client, kotlin-multiplatform, apollo-android, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I've just created a new KMP project from Android studio, added Apollo MP as defined here:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started-multiplatform/

> ```
> plugins {
>   // ...
>   id("com.apollographql.apollo").version("2.5.3")   
> }
>
> sourceSets {
>   // ...
>   commonMain {
>     dependencies {
>       implementation("com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime-kotlin:2.5.3")
>     }
>   }   
> }
> ```

The classes are generated under 'commonMain/build/generated/source/apollo' but i can't access them nor any Apollo classes (e.g. ApolloClient) from the commonMain code.

Also i've noticed that Apollo does not appear under the project External Libraries as well.

From the same link above:

> Add your schema.json and other .graphql files under
> src/commonMain/graphql. Build your module and generated code will be
> available under commonMain sourceSet. That means you can use them both
> in commonMain or platform specific Kotlin code. Once the Kotlin plugin
> builds the iOS Framework, generated code can even be called from Swift
> code.

What am i missing?
Thanks

Comment: Are you targeting other than iOS and jvm?

Comment: Targetting android and iOS

Comment: Hello, @Shirane85! Could you please comment on the current state of the question? If you're able to reproduce it with the original Apollo example, please describe the environment you use(OS, IDE, plugins version, etc)

Comment: Hi @ArtyomDegtyarev, the problem seems like a bug in Android Studio. I built the the project on InteliJ and it works. After that i could continue working with AS.

Comment: Interesting. I'm glad you managed to get rid of the problem. Was it the Android Studio 4.1?

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Yes

Comment: plus 1, have the same problem